# No javadoc in eclipse when trying to see documentation of any resource

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I have this two erros when trying to see some method documentation or anything else of java.

**Note: This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc.
Note: An exception occurred while getting the Javadoc. See log for details.**

It's the first time that happens.

Thanks

Comment: **See log for details.** - so what is in the log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try going to settings and point out the installed JDK folder like this ,

`Window->Preference->`search for 'Jre'in the search field , choose `Installed JRE's->Edit` and change the setting to point to your JDK folder instead of JRE , it worked for me .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows->Preferences -> Installed JRE -> click on the JDK ->JRE Deifination will open -> In RT.JAR attach java source as shown below:

[image: eclipse Installed JRE JRE]